# QGIS version 2.18: Is there a processing tool in version 2.18 that is similar to "Sample raster values" in newer QGIS versions?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I am using a server (Compute Canada) and they have version 2.18 of QGIS loaded. I need to extract values of a raster to points (long/lat) - equivalent to "Sample raster values"- and be able to implement in Python. I have used the point sampling plugin but do not know how to use it in Python. What is the best way to extract values of a raster to points in version 2.18 and to be able to implement it in Python?

Comment: No, I believe there isnt a native tool.

However, you can look at the code for plugins like profile tool and point sampling tool and youshould be able to implement it in python through that.

Comment: Have you been able to implement a plugin in python? Would you have an example to share?